# convert a text file into a list of variables

Tags: python, list, parsing

I have a text file with a set of names (in all caps) and IDs, separated by a colon:

```
NAME1: ID1
NAME2: ID2
NAME3: ID3
...
```

I want to break this out so that

1. the names are in lower case, with spaces represented as "_"
2. everything is reformatted in a different text file

The formatting should be as follows:

```
firstname1_lastname1 = ["ID1"]
firstname2_lastname2 = ["ID2"]
firstname3_lastname3 = ["ID3"]
...
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is "most efficient" really that important, or are you simply looking for us to write the code for you? Reading the file line by line and doing the transformation is likely going to be more than performant enough unless you have millions of lines of data. Perhaps if performance is important, you can share more details such as the size of your dataset and what you've tried that is too slow.

Comment: You'll want to [`split`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) on a colon.

Comment: It also looks like a straightforward `re` call to me, or even using `sed` or `awk` would do.

Comment: Would it be wrong to ask the question, "[What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments note, this is a pretty straightforward task.

It would seem that you're asking for something like this:

```
with open(input_path, 'r') as infile, open(output_path, 'w') as outfile:
  for line in infile:
    line_name, line_id = line.split(':')
    line_name = line_name.strip().replace(' ', '_')
    print('{} = ["{}"]'.format(line_name, line_id.strip()))
```

Comment: I like the `with`, it's something I still don't use often enough.